# Django: Save a FileField before calling super()

Tags: python, django, filefield

I need to save an uploaded file *before* super() method is called. It should be saved, because i use some external utils for converting a file to a needed internal format. The code below produce an error while uploading file '123':

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '/var/www/prj/venv/converted/usermedia/-1/uploads/123_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_...'
```

It seems, that it tries to save it in `super().save()` twice with the same name in an infinite loop. Also, it creates all these files.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    uid = kwargs.pop('uid', -1)
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        if hasattr(field, 'upload_to'):
            field.upload_to = '%s/uploads' % uid

    if self.translation_file:
        self.translation_file.save(self.translation_file.name, self.translation_file)

    #self.mimetype = self.guess_mimetype()
    #self.handle_file(self.translation_file.path)

    super(Resource, self).save(**kwargs)
```

**EDIT:**
Here is inelegant way i wanted to get around (it will double call `save()` method):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    uid = kwargs.pop('uid', -1)
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        if hasattr(field, 'upload_to'):
            field.upload_to = '%s/uploads' % uid

    super(Resource, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.__orig_translation_file != self.translation_file:
        self.update_mimetype()
        super(Resource, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What does translation_file.save() do? I dont see what would cause recursion in this example.

Comment: `translation_file` is defined as FileField. But method is referenced to `FieldFile` in `django.db.models.fields.files.py`. `save()` is defined as `def save(self, name, content, save=True):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an infinite loop in your first example, thats right.
Calling `self.translation_file.save(self.translation_file.name, self.translation_file)` will save the uploaded file to disk and call the Resources class save method again because the methods save paramter defaults to true (have a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#additional-methods-on-files-attached-to-objects) as well as your custom FileField does anyway.

Calling it like this (just add save=False) is more likely to work:

```
self.translation_file.save(self.translation_file.name, self.translation_file, save = False)
```

I hope this points into the right direction.